# Question about File Paths and opening those files C#

Tags: c#, create-directory

I have Three strings that are set to the current: year, month, day respectively using the "DateTimeNow". and I have set a path to a string of the root folder named "Custom_project" by grabbing the file path from a text file on the desktop.

They are named:

```
public string CurrentYear;
public string CurrentMonth;
public string CurrentDay;
public string CustomOrderFilePathTopFolder = File.ReadAllText("C:/desktop/Custom_project.txt");
//CustomOrderFilePathTopFolder now ='s C:/desktop/Custom_project/
```

Okay so I am trying to check to see if a folder exists(Folder Named: "CurrentYear" or in this case "2020" inside of the: "Custom_project" folder) and if not then create the folder with the string, if it does exist then it will then proceed to my next step which is essentially opening the file: "CurrentYear" or "2020, then repeating the same thing but inside of that folder: Custom_project/2020, for month and repeat one last time for day.

So In the end I would have a file path that looks like so: "C:/desktop/Custom_project/2020/07/12".

Now To My Question:
**"HOW DO I GO ABOUT CHECKING IF A FILE NAMED "2020"  EXISTS INSIDE OF THE CUSTOMPATHFOLDER AND IF IT DOESN'T THEN CREATE THAT FOLDER**

I just tried using This(Which doesn't seem to work):

```
        if (CustomOrderFilePathTopFolder == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR FILE PATH CANNOT BE EMPTY!");
        }
        else if (!Directory.Exists(CustomOrderFilePathTopFolder + CurrentYear))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(CustomOrderFilePathTopFolder + CurrentYear);
        }
```

This Does nothing for me so I tried this:

```
        if (CustomOrderFilePathTopFolder == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR FILE PATH CANNOT BE EMPTY!");
        }
        else if (!Directory.Exists(CustomOrderFilePathTopFolder + "/" + CurrentYear))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(CustomOrderFilePathTopFolder + "/" + CurrentYear);
        }
```

Doesn't Work Either So I am At a loss Please Let me know how I would go about this please and thank you a ton!!

Comment: Do you want to check `2020` **directory** exists or not? Because in description you are talking about creating new directory, but in bold sentence you said you want to check **file** exists or not

Comment: So I am trying to see if The File "2020" Exists, if it does then it will continue to the next step and If it Doesn't it will create that folder named "2020" then go to then next step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below steps

- you need to first [combine path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_Path_Combine_System_String___) to point proper file/folder
- Check [File exists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.exists?view=netcore-3.1) or not
- If not, then [create folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.createdirectory?view=netcore-3.1) with same name.

  ```
  using System.IO;
  ...

  var filePath = Path.Combine(CustomOrderFilePathTopFolder, CurrentYear))
  if (!File.Exists(filePath))
  {
      Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);
  }
  ```

Comment: Cool: Would Something like this work too?                                                        
CurrentYear = "/" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();

Comment: No need of `/`, just assign `currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();`

Comment: Cool Thank you! I had now Idea of the Path.Combine

Comment: I attached MSDN documentation link in steps, please go through it. It will be helpful for you to understand what this code does

Comment: Another Quick Question: How would I go about making a text file inside of that folder with the name of  a string, I am trying to point to the folder and then create the text file inside of it, but it creates it next to the folder with the name of the folder it is next to and the string that i assigned to it. for example it creates the file next to folder "12" with the name of "12string", Instead of the file  string being inside of 12 with then name of string.

Comment: Your scenario is not difficult to achieve, I would request you to try it out by yourself. If it did not work out then write a new question with [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)